# Windows 7 jupyter notebook - ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: docker, ipython, tensorflow

I am novice to tensorflow and unix/linux usage. So my questions might be too simple.

I have been running .ipynb files from Anaconda/Jupyter notebook successfully. However after I installed tensorflow using pip, i am getting an error when I try to import tensorflow.

```
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Alternatively I have also downloaded tensorflow image using docker and I can run it from docker container. However I have no clue how to execute .ipynb files (& also how to add that to my docker container with tensorflow)

Comment: You have more that one Python distribution on your computer

Comment: Try conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus tensorflow

Comment: When I try that I am getting the following error.    Fetching package metadata .....            Error. Could not find anaconda.org user conda.anaconda.org.                I am using Anaconda prompt in windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem using [Yaroslav Bulatov's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046448/windows-7-jupyter-notebook-executing-tensorflow/37280604#comment59749704_36046448) from the comments.

Use

`conda install -c http://conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus tensorflow`

instead of

`conda install -c conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus tensorflow`.