# Trouble with TensorFlow in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter

I installed Jupyter notebooks in Ubuntu 14.04 via Anaconda earlier, and just now I installed TensorFlow. I would like TensorFlow to work regardless of whether I am working in a notebook or simply scripting. In my attempt to achieve this, I ended up installing TensorFlow twice, once using Anaconda, and once using pip. The Anaconda install works, but I need to preface any call to python with "source activate tensorflow". And the pip install works nicely, if start python the standard way (in the terminal) then tensorflow loads just fine.

My question is: how can I also have it work in the Jupyter notebooks?

This leads me to a more general question: it seems that my python kernel in Jupyter/Anaconda is separate from the python kernel (or environment? not sure about the terminology here) used system wide. It would be nice if these coincided, so that if I install a new python library, it becomes accessible to all the varied ways I have of running python.

Comment: What error msg did you get? You cannot import tensorflow in Jupyter?

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-41389fad42b5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**Update**

[TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv-installation) supports five installations.

To my understanding, using [Pip installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation) directly would be fine to import TensorFlow in Jupyter Notebook (as long as Jupyter Notebook was installed and there were no other issues) b/z it didn't create any virtual environments.

**Using [virtualenv install](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv-installation) and [conda install](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-installation) would need to install jupyter into the newly created TensorFlow environment to allow TensorFlow to work in Jupyter Notebook** (see the following original post section for more details).

I believe [docker install](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html) may require some port setup in the VirtualBox to make TensorFlow work in Jupyter Notebook ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636925/how-do-i-start-tensorflow-docker-jupyter-notebook?rq=1])).

For [installing from sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources), it also depends on which environment the source code is built and installed into. If it's installed into a freshly created virtual environment or an virtual environment which didn't have Jupyter Notebook installed, it would also need to install Jupyter Notebook into the virtual environment to use Tensorflow in Jupyter Notebook.

**Original Post**

To use tensorflow in Ipython and/or Jupyter(Ipython) Notebook, you'll need to install Ipython and Jupyter (after installing tensorflow) under the tensorflow activated environment.

Before install Ipython and Jupyter under tensorflow environment, if you do the following commands in terminal:

```
username$ source activate tensorflow

(tensorflow)username$ which ipython
(tensorflow)username$ /Users/username/anaconda/bin/ipython

(tensorflow)username$ which jupyter
(tensorflow)username$ /Users/username/anaconda/bin/jupyter

(tensorflow)username$ which python
(tensorflow)username$ /User/username//anaconda/envs/tensorflow/bin/python
```

This is telling you that when you open python from terminal, it is using the one installed in the "environments" where tensorflow is installed. Therefore you can actually import tensorflow successfully. However, if you are trying to run ipython and/or jupyter notebook, these are not installed under the "environments" equipped with tensorflow, hence it has to go back to use the regular environment which has no tensorflow module, hence you get an import error.

You can verify this by listing out the items under envs/tensorflow/bin directory:

```
(tensorflow) username$ ls /User/username/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/bin/
```

You will see that there are no "ipython" and/or "jupyer" listing out.

To use tensorflow with Ipython and/or Jupyter notebook, simply install them into the tensorflow environment:

```
(tensorflow) username$ conda install ipython
(tensorflow) username$ pip install jupyter #(use pip3 for python3)
```

After installing them, there should be a "jupyer" and a "ipython" show up in the envs/tensorflow/bin/ directory.

Notes:
Before trying to import tensorflow module in jupyter notebook, try close the notebook. And "source deactivate tensorflow" first, and then reactivate it ("source activate tensorflow") to make sure things are "on the same page". Then reopen the notebook and try import tensorflow. It should be import successfully (worked on mine at least).

Comment: This actually helped me. Thanks so much Zhongyu

Comment: Its intresting that, when I used virtualenv and python3.4 to install tensorflow, your suggestion on deactivating and then reactivating worked for me! but for another installation which uses python2, it just doesnt work!

Comment: @Hossein what installation did you use? [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv-installation) introduced five installation. I think if you use pip installation, you won't need to do the deactivating stuff. Virtualenv and conda installation would need this. I read somewhere that docker installation requires some setup of the portal on virtual box to enable jupyter, I'm not quite sure about installing from the sources..

Comment: @Zhongyukuang: I believe for the python2, I used anaconda version, and I pretty much installed everything. both, pip, conda, I just started from the very top, and installed all of them to get that to work! and failed. then I created a new ubuntu user and went directly to the virtualenv and thanks to God it worked .I guess my Os or that specific user account is messed up!

Comment: @Hossein Hmm... That's interesting. I had conda python 2.7 installed in my Mac OS, so I just used TensorFlow's conda installation. And things worked out fine. I guess I don't know what went wrong with your python 2.7 TF installation attempt. But I'm glad to hear that eventually you got it to work!

Comment: @ZhongyuKuang any advice on what to do if, after a successful execution of 'sudo pip3 install jupyter' (sudo necessary to overcome a permissions problem) jupyter still does not show up in the envs/tensorflow/bin/ directory?

Comment: @Novak So it sounded like you didn't get any error messages after running `sudo pip3 install jupyter`? In that case, maybe double check which virtual environment did you install jupyter into? Does your command prompt has `(tensorflow)` in front of it, which is an indication of which virtual environment you are in.

Comment: @ZhongyuKuang all of that is correct:  Command prompt had (tensorflow) in front of it.  No errors or warnings but only if I ran as sudo; otherwise, a permission error was the result.  Curiously, though, the ipython install worked and resulted in an ipython entry in the /envs/.... directory.

Comment: @Novak My guess is this is has something to do with `sudo pip3` in conjunction with the virtualenv setting, since `sudo` is installing with root privileges, and according to this [thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/234758/how-to-use-a-python-virtualenv-with-sudo?newreg=729dc0272c07474cb26edc81f59d5fd2), virtualenv settings aren't necessarily carried over. I would suggest either maybe find a workaround with `pip3 install` ((lose `sudo`) to get rid of the error you had, or look up how to do `sudo pip3 install` with virtualenv

Comment: @Novak I'm no expert on OS and I've always found `sudo` and environment variables a bit confusing. But you can maybe try `sudo /Users/username/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/bin/pip3 install jupyter` to force the installation to use the tensorflow virtualenv `pip3` and see if that would work or not.

Comment: Thanks the reinstall of ipython and jupyter and activation/deactivation  worked for me as well.  I was working in windows and found i had to also reinstall basic packages again to get tensorflow working (scipy, numpy).  Using conda install scipy, for example, or conda install scikit-image.  conda picks up the dependencies nicely.

Comment: Something simple to add: I found the line `conda install jupyter` necessary at the end

Comment: @ZhongyuKuang : I did a pip install of tensorflow in my virtualenvironment created using `venv`, and my system installation is of _conda python_ , which has `jupyter-notebook` installed. When I open jupyter-notebook from the virtualenv, and do `pip list` , I see `tensorflow` there, also `which python` and `which pip` shows the virtualenv related path. So, if `pip` shows `tensorflow` in its list, why can't we access, it using system-wide jupyter installation?

Answer (score 10):

i used these following which in virtualenv.

```
pip3 install --ignore-installed ipython
pip3 install --ignore-installed jupyter
```

This re-installs both ipython and jupyter notebook in my tensorflow virtual environment. You can verify it after installation by `which ipython` and `which jupyter`. The `bin` will be under the virtual env.

> **NOTE** I am using python 3.*

Answer (score 4):

I have another solution that you don't need to `source activate tensorflow` before using `jupyter notebook` every time.

**Partion 1**

Firstly, you should ensure you have installed jupyter in your virtualenv. If you have installed, you can skip this section (Use `which jupyter` to check). If you not, you could run `source activate tensorflow`, and then install jupyter in your virtualenv by `conda install jupyter`. (You can use `pip` too.)

**Partion 2**

1.From within your virtualenv, run

```
username$ source activate tensorflow
(tensorflow)username$ ipython kernelspec install-self --user
```

This will create a kernelspec for your virtualenv and tell you where it is:

```
(tensorflow)username$ [InstallNativeKernelSpec] Installed kernelspec pythonX in /home/username/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/pythonX
```

Where pythonX will match the version of Python in your virtualenv.

2.Copy the new kernelspec somewhere useful. Choose a `kernel_name` for your new kernel that is not `python2` or `python3` or one you've used before and then:

```
(tensorflow)username$ mkdir -p ~/.ipython/kernels
(tensorflow)username$ mv ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/pythonX ~/.ipython/kernels/<kernel_name>
```

3.If you want to change the name of the kernel that IPython shows you, you need to edit `~/.ipython/kernels/<kernel_name>/kernel.json` and change the JSON key called `display_name` to be a name that you like.

4.You should now be able to see your kernel in the IPython notebook menu: `Kernel -> Change kernel` and be able so switch to it (you may need to refresh the page before it appears in the list). IPython will remember which kernel to use for that notebook from then on.

[Reference](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs/).

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did to enable tensorflow in Anaconda -> Jupyter.

1. Install Tensorflow using the instructions provided at
2. Go to /Users/username/anaconda/env and ensure Tensorflow is installed
3. Open the Anaconda navigator and go to "Environments" (located in the left navigation)
4. Select "All" in teh first drop down and search for Tensorflow
5. If its not enabled, enabled it in the checkbox and confirm the process that follows.
6. Now open a new Jupyter notebook and tensorflow should work

Answer (score 2):

Your Anaconda install probably went to different directory than your Python install

For instance on my machine I can find location here

```
yaroslavvb-macbookpro:~ yaroslavvb$ which ipython
/Users/yaroslavvb/anaconda/bin/ipython
```

When you type `python`, it tries to find it in `PATH` going in left-to-right order. So you may have another version of `python` in a folder before Anaconda folder, and it'll use that. To fix, you can do `export PATH=....` to change the path, and put Anaconda directory in front, so that it takes `python` from there instead of the default, ie

```
export PATH=/Users/yaroslavvb/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think this is the problem. After doing that, I got a different error message, this time relating to "ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import" (the actual error message is fairly long).

Comment: I think I have the reverse problem, I think that when I start Jupyter the python kernel is using the python installation in the anaconda path, but I want to instead use the python in the /usr/bin path.

Answer (score 1):

I installed PIP with Conda `conda install pip` instead of `apt-get install python-pip python-dev`.

Then installed tensorflow
use [Pip Installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#test-the-tensorflow-installation):

```
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 2.7 
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 2.7 
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v4. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below. 
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

...

`pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL`

Then it will work in jupyter notebook.

Comment: If you are using conda, you should avoid doing "sudo" anything.  Unless you are explicitly trying to do some system-wide install, you should never need sudo rights.  It mostly only leads to confusion and permissions errors.

Comment: @msarahan Thanks! I changed it.

Comment: I use anaconda, and then tensorflow cannot be imported into jupiter notebook on internet explore such as safari. (Tensorflow can be imported if I use terminal to open "ipython" !).   Anyway, after using pip install, the problem solved.https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#using-pip

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer (by Zhongyu Kuang) has just helped me out. Here I've create an `environment.yml` file that enables me to make this conda / tensorflow installation process repeatable.

## Step 1 - create a Conda environment.yml File

`environment.yml` looks like this:

```
name: hello-tensorflow
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - jupyter
  - ipython
  - pip:
    - https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Note:

- Simply replace the name to whatever you want. (mine is `hello-tensorflow`)
- Simply replace the python version to whatever you want. (mine is `3.6`)
- Simply replace the tensorflow pip install URL to whatever you want (mine is the Tensorflow URL where Python 3.6 with GPU support)

## Step 2 - create the Conda environment

With the `environment.yml` being in the current path you are on, this command creates the environment `hello-tensorflow` (or whatever you have renamed it to):

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

## Step 3: source activate

Activate the newly created environment:

```
source activate hello-tensorflow
```

## Step 4 - which python / jupyter / ipython

which python...

```
(hello-tensorflow) $ which python
/home/johnny/anaconda3/envs/hello-tensorflow/bin/python
```

which jupyter...

```
(hello-tensorflow) $ which jupyter
/home/johnny/anaconda3/envs/hello-tensorflow/bin/jupyter
```

which ipython...

```
(hello-tensorflow) $ which ipython
/home/johnny/anaconda3/envs/hello-tensorflow/bin/ipython
```

## Step 5

You should now be able to import tensorflow from python, jupyter (console / qtconsole / notebook, etc.) and ipython.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is very similar with the question post here. [Windows 7 jupyter notebook executing tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046448/windows-7-jupyter-notebook-executing-tensorflow/37280604#37280604). As Yaroslav mentioned, you can try

`conda install -c http://conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus tensorflow` .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when using a custom `Ubuntu 16` image. The problem was related to an existing version of `numpy` that was already installed on my system.

I initially tried

```
sudo pip3 install tensorflow
```

This resulted in the following exception:

> Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 538, in move
>       os.rename(src, real_dst)
>   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy' -> '/tmp/pip-co73r3hm-uninstall/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy'

The docs advise that if you encounter any issues with this command to try the following:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade \ 
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

However, my system was unable to locate `pip3`

> sudo: pip3 command not found

The ulitmate solution was to create a `symlink` for pip3

```
sudo ln -s /anaconda/envs/py35/bin/pip3.5 /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Finally, the following command worked without trouble

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3 install --upgrade \ 
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I verified the installation in the `terminal` and also verified a successful import in my `Jupyter Notebook`

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it is not enough to simply launch ipython  from tensorflow environnement. That is
1) first activate tensorflow virtualenv with:

```
source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
```

2) launch ipython under tensorflow environnement

```
(tensorflow)$ ipython notebook --ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from someone else's post. It is simple and works well!

http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs

Just install the following in the Command Prompt and change kernel to Python 3 in Jupyter Notebook. It will import tensorflow successfully.

> pip install tornado==4.5.3
>
> pip install ipykernel==4.8.2

(Orginial post: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11851)

Answer (score 0):

## Jupyter Lab: ModuleNotFound tensorflow

For a future version of me or a colleague that runs into this issue:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter jupyterlab keras tensorflow
```

Turns out `jupyterlab` is a plugin for `jupyter`.

So even if you are in an environment that has `jupyter` but **not** `jupyterlab` as well, if you try to run:

```
jupyter lab
```

then `jupyter` will look in the `(base)` environment for the `jupyterlab` plugin.

Then your imports in `jupyter lab` will be relative to that plugin and **not** your conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install tensorflow
```

This worked for me in my conda virtual environment.

I was trying to use `conda install tensorflow` in a conda virtual environment where jupyter notebooks was already installed, resulting in many conflicts and failure. But pip install worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

conda info --envs

conda create --name py3-TF2.0 python=3

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

conda activate py3-TF2.0

conda install tensorflow

pip install --upgrade tensorflow

conda install -c anaconda ipykernel

python -m ipykernel install --user --name=py3-TF2.0

it is the best way but if it is required you should upgrade numpy with scipy as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try "conda install tensorflow". This will install TensorFlow in your Anaconda directory.
Your local pip directory might not be shared with the Anaconda directory.

Thanks!

Comment: To use conda to install it to the environment backing the notebook, run `%conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` in a cell in the notebook where you want to use it. Based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow) and use of the magic install command for installing from inside notebooks. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic install commands for use when trying to run install from inside a notebook so that it will go to proper environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I run the next commands.

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

When I open with Jupyter Notebook directly, i doesn't work. But when I open it as shown in this figure, It works for me.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Open an Anaconda Prompt screen:   `(base) C:\Users\YOU>conda create -n tf tensorflow`

After the environment is created type: `conda activate tf`

Prompt moves to (tf) environment, that is: `(tf) C:\Users\YOU>`

then install Jupyter Notebook in this (tf) environment:
`conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab - jupyter notebook`

Still in (tf) environment, that is type
`(tf) C:\Users\YOU>jupyter notebook`

The notebook screen starts!!

A New notebook then can `import tensorflow`

FROM THEN ON
To open a session
click Anaconda prompt,
type `conda activate tf`

the prompt moves to tf environment
`(tf) C:\Users\YOU>`

then type `(tf) C:\Users\YOU>jupyter notebook`

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems. Try to improve that. Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments. To highlight apps' names or interface, use a **bold** (`**` brackets) or *italic* (`*` brackets) font. To start from a new line use *double space* at the end of the line - the question'll be way more clear than using *Enter* everywhere. Adding some `:` would be nice too.

Comment: I knew that my post was not well put together. Y just wanted to contribute an answer of simple implementation, and in the process learn how to contribute to SO.  Thanks a lot for the edits.