# How to get jupyter executing in conda environment?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, environment, conda

I recently learned about environments in conda, as it was necessary to take advantage of the osmnx library.  But I can't get a jupyter notebook to use that environment.

I have followed the instructions/answers/hints from 
[environmental_kernels](http://stuartmumford.uk/blog/jupyter-notebook-and-conda.html), [a similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085665/in-which-conda-environment-is-jupyter-executing)and [this person having the same error on conda_env_dirs](https://github.com/Cadair/jupyter_environment_kernels/issues/20).  To no avail.

I'll outline my steps I've taken so far.

- Created and entered an environment using `source activate OSMNX`
- Open python and confirm osmnx loads (`import osmnx` with no errors).
- Install environment kernels (`pip install environment_kernels`)
- Edit ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py by adding the following two lines:

  ```
  c.NotebookApp.kernel_spec_manager_class = 'environment_kernels.EnvironmentKernelSpecManager'
  c.EnvironmentKernelSpecManager.env_dirs=['~/.conda/envs']
  ```
- Install jupyter in environment (`conda install jupyter`)
- Run `jupyter notebook`

When it runs I see that I can start a new notebook, but only in Python 3.

[image]

When I open an existing notebook, I see the option to change kernels, but again only one option listed.

[image]

And most importantly, when I try to import osmnx, I get an error.

When I run `which python` and `which jupyter` I get two paths:

`which python` : `/Users/scottieb/anaconda/envs/OSMNX/bin/python`

`which jupyter` : `/Users/scottieb/anaconda/envs/OSMNX/bin/jupyter`

It feels like I must have missed a step with environment kernels, but the setup instructions are so simple that there's not much to have overlooked.

Comment: Did you use anaconda2 or anaconda3 while creating the root environment?

Comment: I used the graphical installer for Python 3.6 (https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Comment: I recreated the config, but still no success.  But then I followed these instructions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280739/how-to-make-conda-virtual-environments-persistent-and-available-for-tools-such-a?rq=1) and have it _finally_ working!  Marking this as a duplicate.